# Can anyone suggest a good constraint library for Haskell?

Tags: haskell, package, constraint-programming

I've started learning about [Constraint programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming) and I feel it is something that would work well with Haskell (also I enjoy using Haskell).

Are there any mature constraint frameworks for Haskell?

Answer (score 2):

You can do pure logic programing with [LogicT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/logict).

There's also plenty of interfaces to SAT/SMT solvers.  I wrote [yices-easy](http://mainisusuallyafunction.blogspot.com/2010/09/yices-easy-simple-sat-smt-solving-for.html) in order to learn more about SMT-based constraint programming.

Comment: There is also a [Haskell implementation of Constraint Handling Rules](https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~gregory/haskellchr/) and several [SMT solvers](https://www.google.com/search?q=haskell+%22smt+solver%22).